Is there "Step into my code" debug key in Eclipse like in IntelliJ IDEA?
In IntelliJ IDEA there is convinient debug key "Step Into My Code - Alt-Sift-F7". Is there the same debug key in Eclipse?
(I did not find it in the Eclipse. It allows debug rapidly, step into my code only and do not step into standart ready-use library.)

I think step filters might be what you are looking for.
